# Reading a csv dataset in R where lines and columns are mixed

Tags: r, multiple-columns, rows, mixed

I have downloaded NOOA archive of hurricanes, the original data was a text file that I imported and saved as csv. Now I am trying to reorder the data, unfortunately observation names are mixed (start with 2 characters , i.e AL011851) with dates (with no hyphen). I have tried different things to no avail. How to proceed from there? I would really appreciate any help or ideas.

Here is a dput of the data head:

```
structure(list(date_index = c("AL011851", "18510625", "18510625", 
"18510625", "18510625", "18510625"), time = c("            UNNAMED", 
" 0000", " 0600", " 1200", " 1800", " 2100"), n_entries = c("     14", 
"  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", " L"), type = c("", " HU", " HU", " HU", 
" HU", " HU"), wind = c(NA, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L), newname = c(TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: Only the first value in `data_index` starts with 2 characters. The rest are all numbers.

Comment: I partially solved the problem by filtering out the rows that started with a letter     
     data1<- data %>% 
  filter(!stringr::str_detect(date_index,"^[A-Z]"))                                                                                      by the same token I also lost 1936 names for the observations, Would appreciate another solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you are using the [Atlantic hurricane database (HURDAT2) 1851-2021](https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/data/hurdat/hurdat2-1851-2021-041922.txt) or something very like it.

The issue is that this file is not a very good CSV file. It contains some rows that identify the hurricane, and other rows that contain the data for that hurricane. For example:

```
AL021851,            UNNAMED,      1,
18510705, 1200,  , HU, 22.2N,  97.6W,  80, -999, -999, -999, -999, -999, -999, -999, -999, -999, -999, -999, -999, -999, -999
```

It looks like the first type of row contains the hurricane identifier, name and number of observations. It would be better if those 3 pieces of information were in their own columns, rather than in a row - this would be **tidy data**.

So we will have to tidy the data after reading it into R. Here is one approach:

1. Read the data into R using `read_csv` without a header row
2. Add a column for hurricane ID based on column X1
3. Add a column for hurricane Name based on column X2
4. Add a column for hurricane number of observations based on column X3
5. Fill in the empty values for the 3 new columns
6. Filter out the rows where X1 is not a date
7. Separate the comma-delimited values in column X4 into new columns

Here's a tidyverse approach to achieve the above steps:

```
   library(dplyr)
   library(tidyr)
   library(stringr)
   library(readr)

   hurdat2_1851_2021_041922 <- read_csv("https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/data/hurdat/hurdat2-1851-2021-041922.txt", 
                                        col_names = FALSE)

   hurdat2 <- hurdat2_1851_2021_041922 %>% 
     mutate(ID = ifelse(str_detect(X1, "^[A-Z]"), X1, NA), 
            Name = ifelse(str_detect(X2, "^[A-Z]"), X2, NA), 
            N_obs = ifelse(str_detect(X3, "^\\d+$"), X3, NA)) %>% 
     fill(ID, Name, N_obs) %>% 
     filter(!str_detect(X1, "^[A-Z]")) %>% 
     separate(X4, sep = ",\\s+", into = paste0("X", 4:21))
```

And here is the result (first few lines):

```
   X1       X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9    X10   X11   X12   X13   X14   X15   X16   X17   X18   X19   X20   X21   ID       Name    N_obs
   <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr>   <chr>
 1 18510625 0000  NA    HU    28.0N 94.8W 80    -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  AL011851 UNNAMED 14   
 2 18510625 0600  NA    HU    28.0N 95.4W 80    -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  AL011851 UNNAMED 14   
 3 18510625 1200  NA    HU    28.0N 96.0W 80    -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  AL011851 UNNAMED 14   
 4 18510625 1800  NA    HU    28.1N 96.5W 80    -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  AL011851 UNNAMED 14   
 5 18510625 2100  L     HU    28.2N 96.8W 80    -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  AL011851 UNNAMED 14   
 6 18510626 0000  NA    HU    28.2N 97.0W 70    -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  AL011851 UNNAMED 14   
 7 18510626 0600  NA    TS    28.3N 97.6W 60    -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  AL011851 UNNAMED 14   
 8 18510626 1200  NA    TS    28.4N 98.3W 60    -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  AL011851 UNNAMED 14   
 9 18510626 1800  NA    TS    28.6N 98.9W 50    -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  AL011851 UNNAMED 14   
10 18510627 0000  NA    TS    29.0N 99.4W 50    -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  -999  AL011851 UNNAMED 14
```

Finally, you will want to rename the columns and perhaps convert some of them to the correct type *e.g.* Date for X1. I'm not familiar with the data structure so I'll leave that for you.

Comment: Much Thanks @Neilfws. The codes worked very smoothly and the output is exactly what I needed. Cheers

Comment: Pleased to hear it @PatrickStephenson. Please vote for and accept the answer if it solved your problem.